# Substitution Algebra: How to produce a "y equals" statement

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

$x + 3y = -4$

$y + x = 0$

What are $x$ and $y$?

> I know that in the first problem you replace the $y$ beside the $3$ but I cannot figure out how to turn $y + x = 0$ into a $y=$ statement

Comment: Hint: if $A + B = C$ and $D + E = F$, then $A + B + D + E = C + F$

Answer (score 0):

If you're supposed to use **linear algebra** and Gaussian elimination to solve this problem, then this is most likely what your thought process is supposed to be:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&3&-4\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&3&-4\\0&-2&4\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&3&-4\\0&1&-2\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&-2\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus, we can see that your system is consistent for the unique solution where $x=2$ and $y=-2$.

**Alternatively:** (linear algebra is kind of overkill) You can note that $x+y=0$ and thus $y=-x$. Substitute this into the equation $x+3y=-4$ and you will see that
$$
x-3x=-4\Longleftrightarrow -2x=-4\Longleftrightarrow x=2.
$$
Since $x=2$ and $y=-x$, then $y=-(2)=-2$. Done.